# Biggest Fundamental Force Examples?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, fusion

I know that this question sounds confusing but listen well, What I am asking which phenomenon that happens anywhere in the universe that best represents the four fundamental forces. Nuclear Fusion, Fission, Gravity and Electromagnetism.

here are a couple of examples of what I mean:

- Sun's Core (Nuclear Fusion)
- Black Hole (Gravity)

What I want to know is what are the best examples for the other two forces that are equivalent or close to same cosmic significance as the two phenomenons above.

Comment: It's difficult to think of any normal event here on Earth that doesn't involve the four forces.  What have I missed, sorry?

Comment: The Aurora that you see in the sky are nothing but charged particles interacting with Earth's magnetic field. The sun's core also produces billions of neutrinos which come from the weak force interaction. Another example of electromagnetism are the large charged particle jets seen near quasar cores

Comment: Nuclear fusion and nuclear fission are not fundamental forces. They are types of nuclear reactions. The other two fundamental forces are the strong nuclear force and the weak nuclear force, and both play a role in both of the nuclear reactions you describe (the weak nuclear force plays an especially important role in beta decay, while the strong nuclear force is what keeps quarks inside the proton [a residual effect of the strong force holds protons together in the nucleus]). Also, what does "cosmic significance" mean?

Comment: "cosmic significance" is opinion based (hence my VTC).  From my point of view it is of equal significance that they all work the way they do or I would not be here.  The universe as far as we know has no opinion, and every physicist will have their own idea of what's more important from the minute to the vast.

Comment: read here about the fundamental forces http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html

Comment: @probably_someone What I mean for cosmic significance is where the best examples of the fundamental forces taking place, like what i have described with Sun cores and black holes

Comment: Why are you equating the extreme gravity of a black hole with the relatively mild fusion occuring in the Sun's core?

Comment: @PM2Ring I am not saying that the Sun's Core and the Black Holes are literally equal to each other, just that in the cosmic point of view they are the best examples for some of the Fundamental Forces, and looking for the other fundamental forces that best describe them in the same sense

Comment: Ok. But a black hole is an atypical example of what gravity's like. Through most of the universe, gravity doesn't do all that weird stuff, and you can model it fairly well with Newton's gravitational model.

Comment: The Sun is a fairly typical star that's fusing hydrogen to helium, which has the greatest yield of any fusion reaction, so I guess that makes it a good example. Both the strong & weak interactions are involved in p-p chain fusion: the weak is needed to convert protons to neutrons. Bigger hotter stars also use the CNO cycle, and stars that have fused most of their core hydrogen fuse heavier elements, which burn hotter, but have a smaller mass to energy conversion ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most dramatic example of the strong nuclear force versus EM is the stability of $^{~3}$He. Two protons being held in a stable configuration with only one neutron. The only other stable nucleus with more protons than neutrons is $^{~1}$H with only a proton.  All other stable nuclides have N$\ge$Z.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most dramatic example of the strength of the electrostatic force is atomic fission. Once an unstable nucleus is perturbed strongly enough to shape itself into two separate and smaller nuclei, the force which then propels them violently apart at tremendous speed is electrostatic repulsion.

In the case of the weak force, the type of radioactive decay involving conversion of a neutron into a proton, electron and an antineutrino would be a good candidate. Radioactive decay is the heat source inside the Earth's core, which we experience in a variety of (fairly dramatic) ways here on the surface.

And as you cited in your question, black holes are probably the most dramatic consequence of gravity, and for the strong force it would be the radiation emitted by stars from fusion reactions in their cores.